# Spring Boot RestTemplate to read cookies

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, cookies

I'm new to Spring Boot technology, i'm trying to read cookies information after making call to service, but getting a 302 error code from server. Below is the code using for retrieving the information.

**Existing Spring code**

```
HttpGet get = null;
HttpResponse resp = null;
try {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(authBaseUrl)) {
    get = new HttpGet("Here im using service account url");
    resp = httpClient.execute(get);
    List<Cookie> cookies =   ((DefaultHttpClient)httpClient).getCookieStore().getCookies();
    for (Cookie c : cookies) {
        if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
            LOG.debug(c.getName() + "\t" + c.getValue() + "\t" + c.getPath());
}
        if (c.getName().equals("SMSESSION")) {
         LOG.info("Received auth cookie ");
        }
   }
    EntityUtils.consume(resp.getEntity());
} catch (IOException e) {}
```

**Spring Boot code**

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String plainCreds = "user:pwd";
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
headers.setContentType((MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(headers);
HttpEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange("Here im using   service account url", HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
String resultString = response.getBody();
```

**Response coming as below**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>Given url appended with ?SMSESSION=NO value getting displayed">here</a>.</p>
</body></html>
```

Not sure what causing the issue. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the expected  reponse ? check with the middleware team why it is getting redirected ? does it need JSESSION id to be passed as an header ?

Comment: Yes Barath, its working correctly with Spring code, i'm trying to modify it in spring boot.